Type Argument is not within its bounds in Kotlin
I have a value from the other activity that I want to haul as the new value of my layout text:
val txt:String = intent.getStringExtra("resultval").toString()
The XML part looks like this:
<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id = "@+id/prNumberId"
      android:text = "PR Number"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize = "20sp"
      android:textStyle = "bold"/>

Now, I want to change the text "PR Number" into something like "PR7438927438927". How would I do that? Using this:
findViewById<Text>(R.id.prNumberId).replaceWholeText(txt)
or using:
findViewById<Text>(R.id.prNumberId).textContent = txt
throws me an error saying: Type Argument is not within its bounds.
How can I assign the value of the prNumberId with the new variable I have?
Thank you.
I tried changing the values through the findByViewId and textContent but it doesn't work as it says there is a type argument not within its bounds. It does not accept the R.id.prNumberId as Text.

This happens if you try to declare variable in wrong way.
Here is the correct approach
Kotlin :
val resultval : String = intent.getStringExtra("resultval").toString()
val prNumberTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.prNumberId) 
prNumberTextView.text = resultval

XML :
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id = "@+id/prNumberId"
android:text = "PR Number"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize = "20sp"
android:textStyle = "bold"/>

But as per Google guidelines Android suggest to use data binding.

ahhhh! there, it works! thank you so much. Thought there was something different, never realized it was TextView not Text.

Sure thing. I have done that and chose your answer as the best answer as well.

You could try this.

val txt: String = intent.getStringExtra("resultval").toString()
val prNumberTextView = findViewById(R.id.prNumberId)
prNumberTextView.text = txt

